# Spring Servlet-Context.xml error Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [import]

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring project generated by STS plugin within the eclipse, I am  trying to import a spring-ws file which is in the same directory as servlet-context.xml but getting the error. The servlet context file is listed below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm  http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-1.5.xsd">


    <import resource="spring-ws.xml" />

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />





    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>



    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.crgl.crm" />
    <beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPersistenceUnit" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crgl.crm" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:Services.properties" />
</beans:beans>
```

The error that I get is 
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [import]

Comment: You have made the `mvc` namespace the root, that doesn't contain `import`. You need to prefix your `import` with `beans:` just like your `bean` elements.

Comment: Thanks that helps,need to figure out how to give +1 or more to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your XML you have made the `spring-mvc.xsd` the leading one. The `mvc` namespace doesn't contain an element `import`, the `spring-beans.xsd` however does.

You need to add the `beans` prefix to the `import` element to make it work.

```
<beans:import resource="spring-ws.xml" />
```

Just like with the `bean` tag that is from the same namespace.